# router .use() requires a middleware function but got a string

Tags: ejs

I am using EJS for templating, when I add this

```
app.use("view engine","ejs")
```

in my code i get error.

> router .use() requires a middleware function but got a string

The rest of the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 3000;


const app=express();
app.use("view engine","ejs");



app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var today = new Date();
    var currentDay = today.getDay();
    var day ="";


    if(currentDay === 6 || currentDay === 0){
        day ="weekend";
        
    }else{
        day = "weekday";
        
    }
     res.render("list",{kindOfDay:day});
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('The server has started');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the documentation for using template engines](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html):

> ```
> app.set('view engine', 'pug')
> ```

`use` is used to add middleware, and a string isn't middleware, hence the error message.

You need to use [`set`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set) to set a setting.